# How to make a ADO.Net connection (SQL Server or Oracle database) read-only

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I've tried

```
conn.Connectionstring = conn.Connectionstring + "; Read Only=True";
```

and various variations of that, but they all throw an exception

> Keyword not supported - 'read only'

I fully understand what the exception is specifically telling me, but that doesn't solve my problem, which is how to temporarily to make a connection read only (before I open it), and to restore it to the original state after it is closed.

Comment: Try http://www.connectionstrings.com/ : I found "Mode=Read Only" for SQL Server.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I can't find that approach in the Sql Server pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is not solved in the connection string, but in the user context you use when you open the connection.

If you specify a user who only has rights to read your data, then you have a "read-only" connection.

---

Based off your comment below, the list of acceptable keywords for an ado.net connection is here:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/

I don't think that what you're attempting is possible.  User accounts are how DB access is controlled with ADO.net and SQL server.

Comment: I have to use an existing database login account but temporarily restrict the connection to 'read only', if possible. Otherwise I have to maintain two types of connection, read only and writable, which is not an option.